# Google Developers Console - datastore dashboard inaccessible - Backend Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

In the [new Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), when trying to access:
Storage -> Cloud datastore -> Dashboard / Query / Settings
I get an error saying:

> `Error: Backend Error`

The [old developers console](https://appengine.google.com) functions just fine, with the exception of trying to access:
Data->Datastore admin and displays the message:

> `Error: Not Found`

My project was created using the old console.
Disabling and enabling the `Datastore API` did not help

Related issues:
[Google Console - Cloud Datastore Query returning "Backend Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373545/google-console-cloud-datastore-query-returning-backend-error)
[Google Datastore returning "503 Backend Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855510/google-datastore-returning-503-backend-error)

Comment: hmmm maybe your project doesn't have an associated app engine project associated? Could you try to do the "cloud integration"? it's in the old dev console, under "applications setting" (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Can you pass along your project id (email to eddavisson@google.com) so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Developer Console Internal Error with Datastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463326/google-developer-console-internal-error-with-datastore)